# Django, DRF, Docker, nginx - Server Configuration - Base URL for mediafiles

Tags: django, docker, nginx, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

I am trying to set up my Django Rest Framework application. Unfortunately I still can't manage to get the media files url right.

I tried adding the lines from this answer to my nginx configuration ending up with "Bad Request (400)": [Django Rest framework swagger base url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53115514/django-rest-framework-swagger-base-url)

The application is running on my-domain.com.

**https://my-domain.com/user/**

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "512e0f9f-f08a-4a2d-8e1d-b933a16c0a1f",
            "date_joined": "2021-10-10T11:41:05.077828Z",
            "name": "Maxine Mustermann",
            "user_picture": "**http://127.0.0.1:8337**/mediafiles/images/usr1.jpeg"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Expected**: https://my-domain.com/mediafiles/images/usr1.jpeg (Eventhough the picture can be accessed with this url)

**Returned**: http://127.0.0.1:8337/mediafiles/images/usr1.jpeg

**docker-compose file:**

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data_staging:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.staging.db
    expose:
      - 5432

  web:
    build:
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.staging
    command: gunicorn config.wsgi:application --workers 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume_staging:/home/api/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume_staging:/home/api/web/mediafiles
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.staging
    depends_on:
      - db

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume_staging:/home/api/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume_staging:/home/api/web/mediafiles
    ports:
      - 8337:80
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  postgres_data_staging:
  static_volume_staging:
  media_volume_staging:
```

**nginx.conf:**

```
upstream ae_backend {
    server web:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 75M;
    server_name $DOMAIN www.$DOMAIN;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://ae_backend;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /staticfiles/ {
        alias /home/api/web/staticfiles/;
    }

    location /mediafiles/ {
        alias /home/api/web/mediafiles/;
    }
}
```

Server configuration **nginx/sites-enabled/my-api:**

```
server {

    server_name my-domain.com;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    # add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization';

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8337;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = my-domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name my-domain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization';
}
```

Any help and reference will be appreciated.

Thank you!!

Regards,

Florian

btw: This is my first post on stackoverflow. Please be nice ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I edited this part into my Server nginx config:

```
location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8337;
    }
```

and made sure that my-domain.com ist listed in the "ALLOWED_HOSTS" (settings.py).